# How to call a function on click on the text created by the script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a specific function to be called when clicking on any p-tag text
text. But, it does not work with the text that I create using js
The function that I want to run on clicking on p-tag text

```
$("p").on("rightclick", function () {
  if (opened != 1) {
      $(this).prop('id', 'editable');
      let edit = document.getElementById("edit");
      edit.style.display = "flex";
      $(this).append(edit);
      $("#editable").attr("contenteditable", "true");
      $("#editable").attr("spellcheck", "false");
      $(this).on("keydown", function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        $(this).blur();   
      }
  });
    return (opened = 1);
  }
});
```

The function I use to create text

```
  $('#create-text').click(function() {
  let textpole = $(this).parents().eq(1)
  textpole.append('<p>LoremIpsum</p>');
});
```